# Acumatica - How do I add a new column to InvoiceSplits Selector

Tags: action, customization, acumatica

I need to add UnitCost to the Add Invoice Details Selector screen that appears when Add Invoice is clicked in Sales Order screen when the invoice type is a credit or return. I am new to Acumatica and not sure how I need to do it as an extension.  I added it to InvoiceSplits but when I put breakpoints in there, I never hit them.

I added this code to SOOrderEntry...am I on the right track?

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class InvoiceSplits : IBqlTable
    {
    #region UnitCost
      public abstract class unitCost : PX.Data.IBqlField
      {
      }
      protected Decimal? _UnitCost;

      [PXDBPriceCost()]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unit Cost")]
      public virtual Decimal? UnitCost
      {
        get
        {
          return this._UnitCost;
        }
        set
        {
          this._UnitCost = value;
        }
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate InvoiceSplits CreateInvoiceSplitsDelegate(ARTran artran, SOLine line, SOSalesPerTran sptran, INTran tran, INTranSplit split);
  //  [PXOverride]
    public InvoiceSplits CreateInvoiceSplits(ARTran artran, SOLine line, SOSalesPerTran sptran, INTran tran, INTranSplit split, CreateInvoiceSplitsDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      InvoiceSplits invSplit = new InvoiceSplits();

      invSplit.UnitCost = artran.UnitCost;
      if (tran != null)
      {
        invSplit.UnitCost = split.UnitCost ?? tran.UnitCost;
      }
        return invSplit;
     // return baseMethod(artran,line,sptran,tran,split);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a separate InvoiceSplits class, you would want to make a PXCacheExtension of InvoiceSplits.

```
public sealed class InvoiceSplitsExtension : PXCacheExtension<InvoiceSplits>
{

    #region UnitCost
    public abstract class unitCost : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBPriceCost]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unit Cost")]
    public decimal? UnitCost { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```

Then in the PXOverride of the CreateInvoiceSplits method you would get the CacheExtension and set the UnitCost on that.

```
public delegate InvoiceSplits CreateInvoiceSplitsDel(ARTran artran, SOLine line, SOSalesPerTran sptran, INTran tran, INTranSplit split);

[PXOverride]
public InvoiceSplits CreateInvoiceSplits(ARTran artran, SOLine line, SOSalesPerTran sptran, INTran tran, INTranSplit split, CreateInvoiceSplitsDel del)
{
    InvoiceSplits invSplit = del?.Invoke(artran, line, sptran, tran, split);

    InvoiceSplitsExtension invSplitExt = PXCache<InvoiceSplits>.GetExtension<InvoiceSplitsExtension>(invSplit);

    invSplitExt.UnitCost = artran.UnitCost;

    if (tran != null)
    {
        invSplitExt.UnitCost = split.UnitCost ?? tran.UnitCost;
    }

    return invSplit;
}
```

Lastly, you will need to add your UnitCost field to the UI. To do this you will need to go into a customization package, customize the SO301000 screen and navigate to Dialogs->Dialog: Add Invoice Details->Grid: invoiceSplits on the tree view. Then go to the "Add Data Fields" tab, select your UnitCost field and click create controls.